# How to automatically add and serialize virtual attribute to model object in rails module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, module, decorator

How to decorate `Plugin` object to add automatically virtual `page_links` attribute to attributes if `Plugin` name is `SomePluggin`?

Example:

```
@page.plugins
# As is => [#<Plugin id: 241, url: "some_url", page_id: 118>]
# As I want to be: => [#<Plugin id: 241, url: "some_url", page_links: "1234,main_page,articles", page_id: 118>]
```

Current code:

```
module Cms
  class SomePluggin
    def initialize(plugin)
      @url = plugin.url

      #it doesn't work
      plugin.page_links = "1234,main_page,articles"
      plugin.attributes.merge!("page_links" => "1234,main_page,articles")
      #decorate = SimpleDelegator.new plugin
    end

    def get_content
      puts "content"
    end
  end

  module Pluggin
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      after_initialize :pluggin
    end

    delegate :get_content, to: :pluggin

    attr_writer :pluggin

    def pluggin
      @pluggin ||= "Cms::Pluggin::#{name}".camelize.constantize.new(self) # name=SomePluggin
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :page_links
  belongs_to :page
  include Cms::Pluggin
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `page_links` would be a virtual attribute. Your code structure is complicated, and you can basically add `page_links` and `page_links=` methods to `class Plugin` with initialization, but if you want to keep this attribute in `SomePluggin`, you can do it in this way:

```
module Cms
  class SomePluggin
    attr_accessor :page_links

    def initialize
      self.page_links = "1234,main_page,articles"
    end

    def get_content
      puts "content"
    end
  end

  module Pluggin                                                                                                                                                                         
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      after_initialize :wrap_object
    end

    def wrap_object
      pluggin                                                                                                                                                                            
    end
    delegate :get_content, :page_links, :page_links=, to: :pluggin

    attr_writer :pluggin

    def pluggin
      @pluggin ||= SomePluggin.new
    end                                                                                                                                                                                
  end                                                                                                                                                                                
end
```

Here I've added `:page_links` and `:page_links=` methods to `SomePluggin` and initial value setting in `initialize` method.

Some console output:

```
p = Plugin.new
p.page_links # => "1234,main_page,articles"
p.page_links = '123'
p.page_links # => "123"
```

Comment: Can I merge page_links to Plugin attributes? I need it for AngularJS and only in case when SomePluggin is called, when is called e.g. SomeOtherPlugin I don't need page_links.

Comment: @luzny sorry, but I don't really understand a question. Especially this condition: "when SomePluggin is called". It is being called every time in your code. When do you want this attribute and when do not? Specify what do you mean by "when SomePluggin is called" and "other Plugins" because it isn't clear

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of explanation, I've field `:name` that stores name of plugin, so in my case I create plugin this way: `@pluggin ||= "Cms::Pluggin::#{name}".camelize.constantize.new(attributes)`.

Comment: @luzny remove `attr_accessor :page_links` from `class Plugin` and keep it only in `Cms::`Pluggins you want as I showed. If you will initialize `Cms::SomePluggin` without `attr_accessor :page_links` it will just raise NoMethodError, so in this way you can control which plugins have this attribute and which are not.